# Measuring total load time of a webpage with java

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I'm creating an application to check how long it takes a page to load. So far, I have something like this:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
//load page and wait for it to finish
long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
```

Now, I don't just want to measure how long the html document takes to load, but the entire dom. Basically, if it were in a browser, I'd want it to measure how long it took for the loading spinner to stop.

How can I best do this? I'm trying WebDriver, but it doesn't seem consistent; sometimes it considers the page done while still loading stuff (I tried with an implicit wait, too).

Comment: Are you trying to do this automatically / repeatedly ? If not: most browsers can give you such information with their developer tools.

Comment: @Marged yes, I want this repeatedly/automatically

Answer (score 8):

To get `Load` time as follow:
[image: Chromium Load time]

run the following script:

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class AutomationTests {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    final JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    // time of the process of navigation and page load
    double loadTime = (Double) js.executeScript(
        "return (window.performance.timing.loadEventEnd - window.performance.timing.navigationStart) / 1000");
    System.out.print(loadTime + " seconds"); // 5.15 seconds
  }
}
```

To get the time taken for the page to load once the page is received from the server change:
`window.performance.timing.navigationStart` to `window.performance.timing.responseEnd`

<sub>Tested on Firefox and Chrome.</sub>

Comment: When I run this, i get this error. "The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html". What can i do for this?

Answer (score 1):

In this case you need to wait till some element is displayed. Like this:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

driver.get("Some url");

WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.id("ID of some element"));

long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long elapsedTime = endTime - startTime ;

System.out.println("Total Time for page load - " + totalTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Selenide framework, it already contains a feature in it that gives you timings of all your page components.

[image]