# Capture page load time and size when an element is loaded while page is still loading

Tags: java, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How do we capture page load time and page size while the page is loading(loading not yet completed) and when an element appears.

Through selenium `driver.get(url)` waits till the page load is complete. But here, i wanted to know the time as soon as a particular element appears on the webpage.

As an example consider hitting the url `https://stackoverflow.com/` i wanted to calculate the time as soon as some elements starts appearing on the page(note : page is still loading). Currently i am calculating time and size manually using chrome dev tool's network tab.

Comment: `Currently i am calculating time and size manually using chrome dev tool's network tab` sounds great. Can you show us you work/code please?

Comment: Please refer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245062/how-can-we-get-exact-time-to-load-a-page-using-selenium-webdriver and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34321662/measuring-total-load-time-of-a-webpage-with-java

Comment: @DebanjanB there is no code for this. Open chrome browser and dev tools(network tab), Hit url on the browser and manually check till the content is displayed on the page(redirection requests will be captured in network tab and page load size and load time will also be captured at this point) while the page is still loading.

Comment: @shank087 In the links you mentioned, they are calculating the load time after the page load is completed i.e after `driver.get(url)` statement is executed will for an element and calculate time. What i am looking for is while `driver.get(url)` call is still in process wanted to check for an element and not after the call is completed.

Comment: js `window.performance.timing` gives you various timings(eg: content load time, don start time etc) but this does not seem to give the time when the first/certain element is loaded.